# Application Blocked By Java Security javafx

Tags: java, javafx, безопасность

Создал javafx приложение. Так как прочитал, что javafx приложения могут без проблем запускаться в браузере и/или с браузера через web start, то решил протестировать данную возможность. Упёрся в то, что Java Security требует сертификат. Где взять этот сертификат? Он только платный? Полдня гуглил но так и не понял, как выйти из положения.

Comment: это читали? https://habrahabr.ru/post/202016/

Comment: Прочитал. Не понял что к чему, так как новичок и плаваю в монгих вопросах. Однако там речь идёт о j7, а у меня j8. После гугления я вроде кае понял, что неподписанные приложения больше вообще не будут запускаться.Это так? Второе, я создал в  Netbeans проект javafx appl  простейший с Hello world! кнопкой. Так вот он работает, кнопка появляется на странице в браузере. А вот если создать java fxml appl то браузер почему-то не видит "FXMLMain.xml". Хотя в режиме десктопного приложения проект запускантся. Почему через браузер нет?